# Creating robots dot text

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, robots.txt

I am currently trying to create a robots dot text file to improve my SEO. I am not quite sure were to start. I have read a few tutorials and stay don't feel comfortable making one. Can someone point me to a good source or explain in their answer where I want the robots to be able too crawl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-robotstxt-file) for Magento GO, should give you some more info about robots.txt.
Inchoo also have another good example [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/).
From Inchoo's url:

```
    # Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Dissalow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

Answer (score 0):

The above robots.txt example on [inchoo.net](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/) only works when magento is installed in root directory.

If Magento is installed in a folder for example public_html/shop/ or public/html/magento/ you could use:

- Folder: [Disallow: /*404/](http://ofarm.com.au/robots.txt)

instead of

- Root: Disallow: /404/